# Why can't I install safestrap on galaxy s4 nc1

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, recovery-mode

I am on a galaxy s4 on KitKat and I am rooted with towelroot. When I tried to install safe strap I downloaded 3.7.2 but when I hit install it says it is installing but once its done it says that the recovery is not installed and I confirmed that by booting to recovery. What am I doing wrong? Does safe strap work on galaxy s4 nc1 build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on XDA:

> You can solve Safestrap installation issues by downloading the Selinux Mode Changer app from the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrbimc.selinux&hl=en. Install the app and set selinux to permissive. Done! Please thank @Maribou for this great find!

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2787681

I had the exact same issue and this worked for me.